# Markham window or Anderson window? Who was first?

Tags: patent-infringement

In reference to the patent: [US1116828](https://www.google.com/patents/US1116828)

I found the original patent and the physical model for this patent will cleaning up.  I am interested to know if this preceeds Andersen Window patents. This was my grandfather who was a inventor in Jamestown NY.  We have heard stories that he didn't have enough money to protect this patent.  Andersen manufactured windows starting in 1903.  I can't find the original patent for what they are known for, a window like this.

Answer (score 1):

If you are asking who manufactured windows first, then probably Andersen. Their [history](http://www.andersencorporation.com/about-andersen/history/) states they were manufacturing windows since 1905 at least. That said, examples of double hung sash windows from [at least 1670](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sash_window) still exist. Thus, your grandfather didn't invent the double hung window, he invented a specific implementation which had some advantageous feature sufficiently novel to merit a patent.

Andersen's innovation seems to be called the "two bundle method". From their history page:

> In 1905 Andersen originates the “two bundle” method, which streamlines the
>   window construction process. By standardizing sizes of frame pieces,
>   then packaging them in separate horizontal and vertical pairs, units
>   can be assembled on the job site in as little as 10 minutes. It was
>   nicknamed the 10-Minute Window.

It is not at all clear that Andersen received a patent for this innovation. Patent search tools aren't all that good with such early patents since they need to be scanned. Using patents.google.com I can only find patents listing Andersen as the assignee going back to 1927. However the assignee listed for Andersen could be different in earlier patents and it is possible they licensed another companies patents. In any case, you do not need a patent to sell a product, you only need a patent to protect a specific and novel feature. It is quite likely Andersen's windows at the time (and certainly before 1913) did not implement the novel features as described in your grandfather's patent.

To determine if Andersen or any other window manufacturer infringed on your grandfather's patent, one would need to look at the specific construction of their windows during the term of the patent (roughly 1914 to 1931). Specific technology questions are off topic for this site and this would be more of a history project anyway.

Comment: Thanks Eric! It's fun. I have the mock up window. He has a few other really neat inventions like an angular coil spring. He made a wind up flash light too. I'm just now going through a box of things.  I admire the detail in the drawings and the language used to represent the work.  Other people referenced his work 30-40 years later.

Comment: @CharlieTupitza  Thanks. I have a bunch of patents and wonder if some day my grand kids will read them. If the answer suits you, please consider accepting it.